# Prevent Image Scaling in Android App

Tags: android, bitmap, resize, imageview, bitmapfactory

I have an image that I am downloading from the internet in my android application. I do not want this image to be resized/scaled. Is there anyway I can stop the image from being scaled?

Here is my XML entry for the ImageView:

```
<ImageView 
   android:id="@+id/conditionImage"
   android:scaleType="center"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@id/textMain"
   android:contentDescription="@string/noaaLogoDescription" />
```

Here is my code for showing it in the image view:

```
BitmapFactory.Options bmpOptions = new Options();
bmpOptions.inScaled = false;
URL url = new URL("URLPATHTOIMAGE");
ImageView conditionImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.conditionImage);
InputStream content = (InputStream)url.getContent();
conditionImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(content, null, bmpOptions);

conditionImageView.setImageBitmap(conditionImage);
```

I have tried changing the scaleType in the ImageView XML element to use matrix, center, and centerInside. My last try was using the above code to set inScale to false. Does anyone have any other ideas?

The odd part is this is not happening in the emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adnan, using your example of giving the image view a fixed width and height and also removing the scaleType=centerImage fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try set

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

EDIT:

Not sure why, but changing

```
conditionImageView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.id.conditionImage));
```

to

```
conditionImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.id.conditionImage));
```

solves my problem.

Comment: The image still scaled. The other annoying part, it works fine in the emulator but scales on an actual 4.2 device (Samsung Galaxy S4)

Comment: I'm already attempted that with the adjustViewBounds and wrap_content.

Comment: Not sure why, but changing `conditionImageView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.id.conditionImage));` to `conditionImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.id.conditionImage));` solves my problem. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you put all images in simple "drawable" folder. I mean without extending hdpi,mdpi etc.

Comment: I download the images from a website before displaying them. So I don't have option of putting them in a drawable folder.

Comment: Then give a fix hight and width into your imageView. Eg. android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"                                          You may also set image view size dynamically by getting the downloaded bitmap size if you want to.

Comment: I just tried that... :( I added this and it still resizing the image:

   conditionImageView.setImageBitmap(conditionImage);
   
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams sizeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(conditionImage.getWidth(), conditionImage.getHeight());
   sizeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
   sizeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, textMain.getId());
   
   conditionImageView.setLayoutParams(sizeParams);

Comment: Adnan, using your example of giving the image view a fixed with and height and also removing the scaleType=centerImage fixed the issue.

Comment: Happy to listen that it was useful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple problem. The scaling happens when the ImageView is a lot larger than the rendered image itself. To avoid this ugly pixelated scailing, just "wrap content" the imageview and you should get your original image quality.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by hardcoding `height` of imageview ( as I know it in advance) and then set the `scaleType` as `cropCenter`

see the below code for more clearity.

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```